# UNION ALL affecting datetime variable echoed from database

Tags: php, date

This is my full code:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT dateA AS dateA FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateB AS dateB FROM tableB;
");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $row): 
    $dateA = $row['dateA'];
    ?>
    <div>
    <?php if ($dateA):
        $dateA = date('M d, Y', strtotime($dateA));
        echo $dateA; ?>
    </div>
    <div>
    <?php
        $datetimeA = date('g:ia', strtotime($dateA));
        echo $datetimeA;
    endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is the unwanted result being echoed from this code:

```
May 23, 2019
12:00am       <-- displays wrong time
Aug 23, 2019
12:00am       <-- displays wrong time
```

This is the result that **should** be echoed, but is not:

```
May 23, 2019
1:21am       <-- Correct time as displayed on database column
Aug 23, 2019
6:54pm       <-- Correct time as displayed on database column
```

So how would I rewrite my code so that the correct time is displayed?

EDIT: Updated to include appearance of database tables:

`tableA`

```
Aid | dateA
1   | 2019-05-23 01:21:29
```

`tableB`

```
Bid | dateB
12  | 2019-08-23 18:54:22
```

Comment: Querying (selecting from) a database table normally cannot alter the data contained in that table, so either you do not have the data you think, or PHP is somewhat altering it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes you can alter data from a table - using php's `date()` method. Updated my code to show proof that you can do that. See how `dateA` and `dateB` columns were mostly just numbers? Then they became alphanumerics using the `date()` method. So yes it is possible. There is just something off about the *PDO* code. Before all this was in mysqli OOP code, but when I switched to PDO, this happened.

Comment: That's not what I was commenting on.  I was stating that running select in MySQL won't alter the data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well I need a suggestion on how to work this out and fix this.

Comment: And you are in the best position to do that.  Start by querying directly against MySQL to see what you get.  Then, figure out what is happening on the PHP side of things.

Comment: `$dateA = date('M d, Y', strtotime($dateA));` -> You alter the `$dateA` when reformatting it, that is the problem. Just change the reformatted date variable name to something else then problem solved

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What do you mean by "querying directly against MySQL" - how would I do that?

Comment: @catcon So how would I be able to include `$datetimeA` with the correct time in that code?

Comment: @misner: https://3v4l.org/KFiuN

Comment: @catcon Ohh I see what you mean now. I didn't realize I couldn't use the same variable again. It's just I saw this used somewhere before, so I thought it was acceptable in this case. Thanks! Wish I could've marked you as best answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this. You are saving your converted datepart in same variable, and after that when you are fetching time part from this then it is not there, so giving default value `12:00 AM`. You should use different variable to store your value.

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT dateA AS dateA FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateB AS dateB FROM tableB;
");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $row): 
    $dateA = $row['dateA'];
    ?>
    <div>
    <?php if ($dateA):
        $dateAA = date('M d, Y', strtotime($dateA));    // instead of storing your value in same $dateA use another variable
        echo $dateAA; ?>
    </div>
    <div>
    <?php
        $datetimeA = date('g:ia', strtotime($dateA));
        echo $datetimeA;
    endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: yeah I didn't realize I couldn't store dates in the same variables. Thanks for the explanation, make sense now!